# Python update multilevel dictionary subitems having specific attribute/key

Tags: python, dictionary

Assume I have database-like dictionary, where each item is also dictionary.
For example:

```
{
 'peter' : { 'age' : 28, 'department' : 3857 },
 'helga' : { 'department' : 57, 'occupancy' : 'graphics' },
 'eugene' : { 'age' : 48, 'department' : 12, 'role' : 'teamlead' }
 }
```

I want update all ages to 30, but only those entries that already have 'age'. The above example should look like this after update:

```
{
 'peter' : { 'age' : 30, 'department' : 3857 },
 'helga' : { 'department' : 57, 'occupancy' : 'graphics' },
 'eugene' : { 'age' : 30, 'department' : 12, 'role' : 'teamlead' }
 }
```

Of course it is possible to do with nested `for`s and `if`s, checking whether `'age' in entry`, but I believe should be elegant pythonic way.
I guess it should be something with generator, but can't figure how to do it right.

Comment: I don't think there's a more elegant way than a loop with `if`.

Comment: There may be a way with a dictionary comprehension, but it will *not* be clearer.

Comment: `for subd in d.values(): if 'age' in subd: subd['age'] = 30`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski That's the loop he doesn't want. It's apparently not "pythonic"enough"

Comment: @Barmar: He said nested `for`s and `if`s so I have not idea what he meant.  There's no nesting there.

Comment: I guess he means an `if` nested inside a `for`, although why he thinks that's not elegant is unclear.

Comment: @Barmar I'm kind of newbie in Python and wanted use this opportunity to learn something great. Python surprised me many times, so thought maybe here is alternative ways :)

Comment: There's no shortcut for "update a dictionary key only if it exists". So this is a case where the obvious code is also the simplest.

Comment: A note about "not elegant". My actual 'database' is a bit more complex, i.e. few levels of nesting and the key I am checking is not at top level. Doing it with `for` and `if` looks somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: @Barmar you said 'only if exists'. Assume that all entries in dictionary have subkey 'age'. Does it change anything? Is there alternative way?

Comment: Then you could use the `.update()` method in a loop or a dictionary comprehension with the `|` operator.

Comment: But just because it's a one-liner doesn't make it more elegant. The conditional operator is often more confusing.

Comment: I agree. But my primary objective - learn alternative ways Python can do stuff or look at a problem by different angle. Maybe specifically in this context the answer given by Unmitigated is not marvelous, but I learned from it that I can use `or` on dictionaries. Can come handy in another situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dict comprehension to create a new dictionary, but it is much simpler and more direct to just use a for loop.

```py
res = {k : v | ('age' in v and {'age': 30} or {}) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: I knew there should be some monstrous single-liner :) Thanks!

Comment: I think this would be more readable: `{k : v | {'age': 30} if 'age' in v else v for k, v in d.items()}`